# Implement IF-ELSE as a procedure in Lisp/Ruby

Tags: ruby, lambda, lisp, sicp

I'm reading the lambda calculus section(chapter 4) of [Understanding Computation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449329276). This code try building `MOD` with lambda calculus in Ruby:

```
MOD = -> m { -> n { CONTROL_IF[
            IS_LESS_OR_EQUAL[n][m]
            ][
                MOD[SUBTRACT[m][n]][n]
            ][
                m
            ]
        }}

CONTROL_IF = -> b { b }
IS_LESS_OR_EQUAL = -> m { -> n { IS_ZERO[SUBTRACT[m][n]] }}
IS_ZERO = -> n { n[-> x { B_FALSE }][B_TRUE] }
#Full code would listed below
```

irb fail and print `SystemStackError: stack level too deep`

when entered `to_integer(MOD[THREE][TWO])`

According to the book, `MOD` doesn't work since it fail to implement the lazy evaluation of Ruby `if-else` control logic and keeps calling itself recursively.

And it works after modifying:

```
#working one
MOD = -> m { -> n { CONTROL_IF[
            IS_LESS_OR_EQUAL[n][m]
            ][
              -> x { MOD[SUBTRACT[m][n]][n][x]}
            ][
              m
            ]
        }}
```

It is said that `-> x { ...[x]}` delay the recursive calling of `MOD` but I don't get it.

Further, it occurs to me a similar exercise(1.6) in SICP:

```
(define (new-if predicate then-clause else-clause)
    (cond (predicate then-clause)
        (else else-clause)))

(define (sqrt-iter guess x)
    (new-if (good-enough? guess x)
            guess
            (sqrt-iter (improve guess x) x)))
```

As a user-defined procedure, `sqrt-iter` runs into infinite recursion because `(sqrt-iter (improve guess x) x)` is evaluated every time as an argument of procedure `new-if`.

So now I understand that key point of implementing `IF-ELSE` as a procedure is lazy evaluation and my question is:

1. **Why could the** `MOD` **be working after modification?**
2. **Can the** `new-if` **be improved in the Ruby way (**`-> x { ...[x]}`**) so as to delay recursive calling?**

Full code of Ruby:

```
ZERO  = -> proc { -> x {                          x      } }
ONE   = -> proc { -> x {                     proc[x]     } }
TWO   = -> proc { -> x {                proc[proc[x]]    } }
THREE = -> proc { -> x {           proc[proc[proc[x]]]   } }
FOUR  = -> proc { -> x {      proc[proc[proc[proc[x]]]]  } }
FIVE  = -> proc { -> x { proc[proc[proc[proc[proc[x]]]]] } }

def to_integer(proc)
    proc[-> n { n + 1 }][0]
end

CONTROL_IF = -> b { b }

B_TRUE  = -> x { -> y { x }}
B_FALSE = -> x { -> y { y }}
IS_ZERO = -> n { n[-> x { B_FALSE }][B_TRUE] }

IS_LESS_OR_EQUAL = -> m { -> n { IS_ZERO[SUBTRACT[m][n]] }}

ADD      = -> m { -> n { n[INCREMENT][m] } }
SUBTRACT = -> m { -> n { n[DECREMENT][m] } }

PAIR  = -> x { -> y { -> f { f[x][y] } } }
LEFT  = -> p { p[-> x { -> y { x } } ] }
RIGHT = -> p { p[-> x { -> y { y } } ] }

INCREMENT = -> n { -> p { -> x { p[n[p][x]] } } }

SLIDE     = -> p { PAIR[RIGHT[p]][INCREMENT[RIGHT[p]]] }
DECREMENT = -> n { LEFT[n[SLIDE][PAIR[ZERO][ZERO]]] }

=begin
#failed one
MOD = -> m { -> n { CONTROL_IF[
            IS_LESS_OR_EQUAL[n][m]
            ][
                MOD[SUBTRACT[m][n]][n]
            ][
                m
            ]
        }}
=end

#working one
MOD = -> m { -> n { CONTROL_IF[
            IS_LESS_OR_EQUAL[n][m]
            ][
              -> x { MOD[SUBTRACT[m][n]][n][x]}
            ][
              m
            ]
        }}

#to_integer(MOD[THREE][TWO])
```

Comment: See also [tail call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call).

Answer (score -1):

I am not that familiar with Ruby syntax, but it seems you are placing an anonymous function in place where the expression would have been. An anonymous function does produce the desired delay, since it does not evaluate the body until called. The question is how it is called and by where. Introducing such an "in-place" delays lead to very confusing code in general.

In Scheme you can make a delayed version of `if` but with slightly different semantics:

```
(define (new-if test consequent alternative)
       (cond (test (consequent))
             (else alternative)))
> (new-if (= (+ 1 2) 3) 
                 (lambda () (display "Yay"))
                 (lambda () (display "Nei")))
Yay
```

So, the consequent and alternative need to be passed as anonymous functions. Notice, this version still uses special form `cond`. If you want to go all the way to basics and define `if` just via lambda-functions in a language with applicative order of evaluation (i.e. strict like Scheme), you are setting yourself up to a very difficult task to control where the expression is delayed and where it is not.